# Parse an InputStream for multiple patterns

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, inputstream

I am parsing an InputStream for certain patterns to extract values from it, e.g. I would have something like

```
<span class="filename"><a href="http://example.com/foo">foo</a>
```

I don't want to use a full fledged html parser as I am not interested in the document structure but only in some well defined bits of information. (Only their order is important)
Currently I am using a very simple approach, I have an Object for each Pattern that contains a char[] of the opening and closing 'tag' (in the example opening would be `<span class="filename"><a href="`and closing `"` to get the url) and a position marker. For each character read by of the InputStream, I iterate over all Patterns and call the `match(char)` function that returns true once the opening pattern does match, from then on I collect the following chars in a StringBuilder until the now active pattern does match() again. I then call a function with the ID of the Pattern and the String read, to process it further.
While this works fine in most cases, I wanted to include regular expressions in the pattern, so I could also match something like

```
<span class="filename" id="234217"><a href="http://example.com/foo">foo</a>
```

At this point I was sure I would reinvent the wheel as this most certainly would have been done before, and I don't really want to write my own regex parser to begin with. However, I could not find anything that would do what I was looking for.
Unfortunately  the `Scanner` class only matches one pattern, not a list of patterns, what alternatives could I use? It should not be heavy and work with Android.

Comment: I wonder if your input is well formed in the XML sense

Comment: not at all, the html may be invalid

Answer (score 5):

You mean you want to match any `<span>` element with a given `class` attribute, irrespective of other attributes it may have?  That's easy enough:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"), "UTF-8");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "<span[^>]*class=\"filename\"[^>]*>\\s*<a[^>]*href=\"([^\"]+)\""
);
while (sc.findWithinHorizon(p, 0) != null)
{
  MatchResult m = sc.match();
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The file "test.txt" contains the text of your question, and the output is:

```
http://example.com/foo
and closing
http://example.com/foo
```

Comment: No, I also want to match other patterns like
    <input … name="delete" value="123456">… (the value)
or
    <blockquote>Text</blockquote> (the text)
and distinguish between the different patterns.

Answer (score 0):

the [Scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) API seems to be what you're looking for. You would have to use an OR (|) separated pattern string.

This pattern can get really complicated really quickly though.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to think this has all been done before :) What you are talking about is a problem of tokenizing and parsing and I therefore suggest you consider JavaCC.

There is something of a learning curve with JavaCC as you learn to understand it's grammar, so below is an implementation to get you started.

The grammar is a chopped down version of the [standard JavaCC grammar for HTML](http://mindprod.com/javacc/html-3.2.jjt). You can add more productions for matching other patterns.

```
options {
  JDK_VERSION = "1.5";
  static = false;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(eg1)
import java.util.*;
public class eg1 {
  private String currentTag;
  private String currentSpanClass;
  private String currentHref;

  public static void main(String args []) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println("Starting parse");
    eg1 parser = new eg1(System.in);
    parser.parse();
    System.out.println("Finishing parse");
  }
}

PARSER_END(eg1)

SKIP :
{
    <       ( " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" )+   >
|   <       "<!" ( ~[">"] )* ">"            >
}

TOKEN :
{
    <STAGO:     "<"                 >   : TAG
|   <ETAGO:     "</"                >   : TAG
|   <PCDATA:    ( ~["<"] )+         >
}

<TAG> TOKEN [IGNORE_CASE] :
{
    <A:      "a"              >   : ATTLIST
|   <SPAN:   "span"           >   : ATTLIST
|   <DONT_CARE: (["a"-"z"] | ["0"-"9"])+  >   : ATTLIST
}

<ATTLIST> SKIP :
{
    <       " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r"    >
|   <       "--"                        >   : ATTCOMM
}

<ATTLIST> TOKEN :
{
    <TAGC:      ">"             >   : DEFAULT
|   <A_EQ:      "="             >   : ATTRVAL

|   <#ALPHA:    ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_","-","."]   >
|   <#NUM:      ["0"-"9"]                       >
|   <#ALPHANUM: <ALPHA> | <NUM>                 >
|   <A_NAME:    <ALPHA> ( <ALPHANUM> )*         >

}

<ATTRVAL> TOKEN :
{
    <CDATA:     "'"  ( ~["'"] )* "'"
        |       "\"" ( ~["\""] )* "\""
        | ( ~[">", "\"", "'", " ", "\t", "\n", "\r"] )+
                            >   : ATTLIST
}

<ATTCOMM> SKIP :
{
    <       ( ~["-"] )+         >
|   <       "-" ( ~["-"] )+         >
|   <       "--"                >   : ATTLIST
}



void attribute(Map<String,String> attrs) :
{
    Token n, v = null;
}
{
    n=<A_NAME> [ <A_EQ> v=<CDATA> ]
    {
        String attval;
        if (v == null) {
            attval = "#DEFAULT";
        } else {
            attval = v.image;
            if( attval.startsWith("\"") && attval.endsWith("\"") ) {
              attval = attval.substring(1,attval.length()-1);
            } else if( attval.startsWith("'") && attval.endsWith("'") ) {
              attval = attval.substring(1,attval.length()-1);
            }
        }
        if( attrs!=null ) attrs.put(n.image.toLowerCase(),attval);
    }
}

void attList(Map<String,String> attrs) : {}
{
    ( attribute(attrs) )+
}


void tagAStart() : {
  Map<String,String> attrs = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
{
    <STAGO> <A> [ attList(attrs) ] <TAGC>
    {
      currentHref=attrs.get("href");    
      if( currentHref != null && "filename".equals(currentSpanClass) )
      {
        System.out.println("Found URL: "+currentHref);
      }
    }
}

void tagAEnd() : {}
{
    <ETAGO> <A> <TAGC>
    {
      currentHref=null;
    }
}

void tagSpanStart() : {
  Map<String,String> attrs = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
{
    <STAGO> <SPAN> [ attList(attrs) ] <TAGC>
    {
      currentSpanClass=attrs.get("class");
    }
}

void tagSpanEnd() : {}
{
    <ETAGO> <SPAN> <TAGC>
    {
      currentSpanClass=null;
    }
}

void tagDontCareStart() : {}
{
   <STAGO> <DONT_CARE> [ attList(null) ] <TAGC>
}

void tagDontCareEnd() : {}
{
   <ETAGO> <DONT_CARE> <TAGC>
}

void parse() : {}
{
    (
      LOOKAHEAD(2) tagAStart() |
      LOOKAHEAD(2) tagAEnd() |
      LOOKAHEAD(2) tagSpanStart() |
      LOOKAHEAD(2) tagSpanEnd() |
      LOOKAHEAD(2) tagDontCareStart() |
      LOOKAHEAD(2) tagDontCareEnd() |
      <PCDATA>
    )*
}
```

Comment: Hm, this seems like an overkill, if I get it right I also would have to recompile the application if the specification changes, and not just adjust a config file and reload it.